# mock.patch leaks mocked object outside the scope of with statement

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, patch

I have below three python files under folder controller/

1. math.py

```
class Math:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def addition(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

2. calculation.py

```
from controller.math import Math


def perform_addition():
    math = Math(1, 2)
    return math.addition()
```

3. test_sample.py

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

def test_addition():


    mock_math = MagicMock()

    with patch('controller.math.Math', return_value=mock_math) as MockClass:
        instance = MockClass.return_value

        instance.addition.return_value = 100

        from controller.calculation import perform_addition
        output = perform_addition()

        print(output)  # prints 100

    post_patch_output = perform_addition()
    print(post_patch_output)  # prints 100 but expected 3
```

When I execute test_addition, I expect `post_patch_output` to return 3 but it return 100 i.e. the mocked output. I am curious what I am missing here?

From the documentation of mock.patch [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch), it says that `When the function/with statement exits the patch is undone.` which doesn't look like the case here

Answer (score 0):

#### Corrections to the function `test_addition`

You have to modify the file `test_sample.py` as show below:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from controller.calculation import perform_addition

def test_addition():

    mock_math = MagicMock()

    #with patch('controller.math.Math', return_value=mock_math) as MockClass:
    with patch('controller.calculation.Math', return_value=mock_math) as MockClass:
        instance = MockClass.return_value

        instance.addition.return_value = 100

        #from controller.calculation import perform_addition
        output = perform_addition()
        print(output)  # prints 100

    post_patch_output = perform_addition()
    print(post_patch_output)  # prints 100 but expected 3

test_addition()
```

This is the output of the execution of `test_addition()`:

```
100
3
```

as you expected.

#### The errors in your code

- You have to patch the object referenced by the name `Math` inside the file `calculation.py` and not inside `math.py`. If you patch `controller.math.Math` all reference to `Math` points to a Mock object. So every times you call `perform_addition()` it is used the Mock object and not the real class `Math`
- The previous modification is enough but I preferred to execute the import `from controller.calculation import perform_addition` at the top of the file and not inside the method `test_addition`
- Remember that when you execute an `import` (even inside a context manager) the name imported (in your case `perform_addition`) is available in the script and refers to an object.